# Stuck at water temple, where I have to jump over the geysers

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

In my quest to get the boss key, I'm stuck at the room with the three geysers and the tektites. I killed the tektites, and I'm now trying to jump over the geysers to the other side of the room. The problem is that I can't jump to the first geyser at all. I just fall against it (see screenshot).

[image: Link jumps against a geyser]

Note: I'm playing on the Project64 emulator (version 1.6).

Comment: Yea in ocarina of time auto jump (http://zeldawiki.org/Autojump) was implemented, so I should be jumping automatically.

Comment: You should upvote and/or accept my answer (assuming that it helped) since your problem has been solved, otherwise, this question will get bumped by Community on a regular interval and keep showing up on the front page.

Comment: If you feel that you still can't make it after many attempts, try to roll-jump (time a roll so you are halfway through the animation as you reach the edge) because roll-jumps have a farther jump than the normal auto-jump.

Answer (score 3):

From [this guide](http://www.thonky.com/ocarina-of-time/water-temple), it looks like you have the right idea, but your jumps aren't quite angled right.

> Use your arrows to kill the tektites across the way. **The floor switch makes not one but three water spouts rise (and not in a straight line), so step on the switch and carefully jump across them to the door.** Exit.

If a regular jump doesn't work for you, try a roll jump, like Cyberson suggested. You will get more distance from it than a regular jump.

Comment: I think I'm now trying at the right angle, but Link just doesn't want to jump.

Comment: If I roll at the right moment, then I can jump to the first spout and then to the second, haven't reached the third yet, but I hope it will work.

Comment: @Michthan It sounds like that's the solution, then.

Comment: @Michthan That's it, make sure to take a step or two then roll jump. If there is a hook anchor on the other side, jump to the first or second and then hookshot the rest if possible and you really can't land the jumps.

Comment: I got over by rolling before every jump and that made it possible for me. I also noticed that my range of motion was set to 50% and I think if it was at 100 % then I would have jumped automatically.

Comment: @Michthan, okay cool, so this was the solution?

Comment: @Michthan done :)

Answer (score -3):

Do you play 60 fps. There are some problems with the hookshot not reaching far enough and other problems, if you run the game 60 fps. Try the original and see if you get further.

Comment: There is no hookshot anchor in this room, look at the image.